# TextAngular custom toolbar button onElementSelect not working for table/tr/td

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textangular

I have implemented a custom button that allows a user to add a table to the editor, which works fine.  However, I can't seem to get the `onElementSelect` to fire when clicking in the newly added table.  The goal is that when a user clicks on a table, a popover will displayed that will allow the user to edit the number of columns/rows. For now, I'm just triggering an alert.

```
taRegisterTool('insertTable', {
      iconclass: 'fa fa-table',
      tooltiptext: 'Insert table',
      onElementSelect: {
        element: 'td',
        action: function(event, $element, editorScope){
         alert('table clicked!');
         // once we get here, I will add the necessary code to implement the table editor
      },
      action: function($deferred){...

        ...
    });
    taOptions.toolbar[1].push('insertTable');
```

I have tried setting the element to `td`, `tr`, `tbody`, and `table`, but none of those work.  If I set it to `a` or `img`, clicking on one of those elements in the editor fires the alert.

I've added custom toolbar buttons for inserting links and images and those work fine using this method. 
Does `textAngular` not allow selection of the table elements?

Plunkr of where I'm stuck: http://plnkr.co/edit/tm1dMv?p=preview

Comment: First of all in the snippet provided there is badly defined object. Second `action` is a duplicate key in the `onElementSelect` object. If it's just the case of typing mistake and original code doesn't contain it please correct the question

Comment: Can you elaborate on an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NixE6HylQmheXg2CUomv?p=preview)?

Comment: @KirillSlatin - Sorry for the delay.  I have added a plunkr to the question.  http://plnkr.co/edit/tm1dMv?p=preview

Comment: [Official docs](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/wiki/Customising-The-Toolbar) even don't have `onElementSelect` mentioned. This seem to be some kind of internal thing. According to sources it triggers `ta-element-select` event AND it can only be applied to `a` and `img` tags. At the same time `ta-bind` seems to be isolating its scope so you can't even provide your custom `ng-click` handler on the table. Sorry, I don't think I can help much. I suppose the best option would be to open an issue on github and ask author of textAngular directly

Comment: @KirillSlatin, I was hoping to get him to answer here, since the question was originally just how do I do "x".  I hate opening issues on github pages if its not really a bug.  But it sounds like this may be something he could "fix" in a later version.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much digging, I found the following:

In the textAngularSetup.js file, around line 55, you can add additional elements that you would like to be able to create click events on.

```
.value('taSelectableElements', ['a','img','td'])
```

That's it!

Plunkr updated with working example:  http://plnkr.co/edit/tm1dMv?p=preview